# How to generate serial Nos in a Column which resets after S.No 1 to 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table "X" is a truncate and load table every hour with Column "A" .Table "X" can have either 5 or >5 or <5 records in every run.

Need help with T-SQL query for the following :

Want to add a column "CounterNumber" to table "X" which inserts a serial number from 1 to 5 for the first 5 inserted records.

Once the first 5 inserted records are give serial number from 1 to 5  , the next 6th inserted record should have the serial number as 1 , the 7th inserted record should have the serial number as 2 and so on.

In short the serial number should repeat from 1 to 5 after every 5th record.

Expected Result, note the SerialNo repeats after every 5th Record:

```
+---------------+---------+
| CounterNumber | ColumnA |
+---------------+---------+
|             1 | Order1  |
|             2 | Order2  |
|             3 | Order3  |
|             4 | Order4  |
|             5 | Order5  |
|             1 | Order6  |
|             2 | Order7  |
+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly overkill for your application, and contingent on SQL Server 2012 or above, but a SEQUENCE object could do the job.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.OrderSerialNumber  
   AS tinyint  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1  
    MINVALUE 1  
    MAXVALUE 5  
    CYCLE;  
GO  

-- At runtime:

ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.OrderSerialNumber 
RESTART WITH 1; 

INSERT X (CounterNumber, ColumnA)
SELECT 
    NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.OrderSerialNumber AS CounterNumber,
    OrderData.*
FROM
    WhereEverYourDataComesFrom;
```

Of course, if someone else discovers the Sequence and starts pulling numbers from it, it could throw you off, but appropriate security could address that.

Comment: This helped me ...the identity column solution fails due to gap.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add at least 2 columns for that: One column for identity, and one computed column for the 1-to-5 serial number:

```
ALTER TABLE X
ADD id int identity(1,1),
    Nos as (CASE WHEN id % 5 = 0 THEN 5 ELSE id % 5 END);
GO
```

**Testing:**

Your existing table:

```
CREATE TABLE X
(
    A int
);
```

Alter statement:

```
ALTER TABLE X
ADD id int identity(1,1),
    Nos as (CASE WHEN id % 5 = 0 THEN 5 ELSE id % 5 END);
GO
```

Insert values:

```
INSERT INTO X VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
```

Test:

```
SELECT *
FROM X;
```

Results:

```
A   id  Nos
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
5   5   5
6   6   1
7   7   2
8   8   3
9   9   4
10  10  5
```

Trancate, insert, and test again:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE X;

INSERT INTO X VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);


SELECT *
FROM X;
```

Results:

```
A   id  Nos
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
5   5   5
6   6   1
7   7   2
8   8   3
9   9   4
10  10  5
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/FIZHF59964)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check on this

Comment: I've added a live demo link at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, you rely on `identity` generating numbers without gaps. This is not guaranteed.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Actually, I rely on identity generating a single batch of numbers without gaps. True, that is not guaranteed, but it's fairly safe to assume no gaps within a single insert statement. A safer solution would be to create a UDF to count the rows before current, but that's a more cumbersome solution and it has worst performance.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Zohar
Little simpler to start iden on 0

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[oneFiveB](
    [iden] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [oneFive]  AS ([iden]%(5)+(1)),
    [val] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If identity has a gap (which it can) then this fails

Comment: I think I would post that as a comment on the original answer instead of posting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am giving another solution if you cant change your table:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/552fd/7

```
with cte as (
  select *,
  rwnum=row_number() over (order by cntnbr,[order])
  from x
  )
  select *,
  newcol=(case when rwnum % 5 = 0 then 5 else rwnum % 5 end)
  from cte
```